# Customizing Cognos 11.1.6 Connection Portal

Tags: connection, ibm, cognos

Previously in **Cognos 10** you could **customize the connection portal** by adding a company logo and/or fonts and colors. These settings could be changed by editing the **banner.css file on the gateway web server and editing the system.xml file on the app tier**.

I installed **Cognos 11.1.6** but it looks like the steps previously used to update these environment configurations are **no longer used**, or this is **no longer the preferred method to make the changes**. I'm looking to **add a company logo and to edit some colors to the connection portal**. If somebody has experience with this in **Cognos 11** I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under APP directory Try to look for them first: ca_customvis or SampleTheme.zip